# How to wrap parts of your existing webpage in 3 divs next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have made already a webpage, so the elements are already there and in place.
As you can see in the example, the main part of the page has a very distinctive
structure:
 **left - menu circles**   
 **middle - text**  
  **right - pictures**

I want to make 3 seperate divs, a div for the circles, div for the text and a div for the pictures. Is there a way to do that without actually changing the look of the website.

It is so that other people can edit the webpage more easily later on.

https://plnkr.co/edit/YhS1I3nfW3UCqUIK2p8o?p=preview

```css
.smallmenu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 436px;
  width: 100%;
}

.circlemenu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 106px height: 107;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  border: solid 2px #73B7DB;
  background: #73B7DB;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 440%;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.circle {
  border: solid 2px #73B7DB;
  background: #73B7DB;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 440%;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.paragraphs {
  margin: 7% 40% 2% 15%
}

.imageleft {
  float: left;
  margin: 00% 10% 10% -20%;
}

.imageright {
  float: right;
  margin: -5% -80% 10% 10%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 174px
}

#hovermenu:hover {
  border: solid 2px #464646;
  background: #464646;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 440%;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.quizbox {
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 950px;
  border: 1px gray solid;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: #00A7AE;
  margin-top: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background: #73B7DB;
}

.row {
  text-align: left;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

span#answer1,
#answer2,
#answer3,
#answer4,
#answer5,
#answer6,
#answer7,
#answer8,
#answer9,
#answer10,
#answer11,
#answer12,
#answer13,
#answer14,
#answer15,
#answer16 {
  display: inline;
  color: green;
  margin-right: 30%;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  padding: 10px 15px 11px !important;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  background-color: #00995D;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #57D6C7;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) inset;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 24pt;">Mit dem Fahrrad zur Schule? Aber sicher!</span></p>
<p style="margin: 2% 20% 2% 20%;">Es gibt viele gute Gründe, mit dem Fahrrad zur Schule zu fahren. Lerne sie kennen und plane deine persönliche, sicherste Route.</p>
&nbsp;
<div class="smallmenu">
  <a class="circlemenu" href="#why" id="hovermenu">
    <font color="white">Warum</font>
  </a>
  <a class="circlemenu" href="#what" id="hovermenu">
    <font color="white">Was</font>
  </a>
  <a class="circlemenu" href="#how" id="hovermenu">
    <font color="white">Wie</font>
  </a>
  <a class="circlemenu" href="#quiz" id="hovermenu">
    <font color="white">Quiz</font>
  </a>
</div>
&nbsp;

<hr width="100%" />

<div class="paragraphs">

  <a class="imageleft circle" id="why">
    <font color="white">Warum</font>
  </a><img class="imageright" src="http://ideaslab.sbg.ac.at/ideaslab/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/why300x200-300dpi.jpg" />Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem
  IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum.

</div>
```

Comment: Yes you can do that first make a container { width: 100%; position: relative; float: left;} ... Under this make three div's , set a fixed width height and float left { width: px; height: px; float: left; }

Comment: You already have distinct elements for the circle and the image there ... only the text is not wrapped into a container element yet. So of course you can wrap those into additional divs, if you like. You might have to adapt the CSS accordingly after that.

Comment: @BlackPanther I'm very curious to see this work without changing the look of the website

Comment: there is also grid display. **Breaking content appart doesn't make much sens in my opinion** . (screen readers or searching engines won't get it)  unless content are dispatch within a table to make it readable and making sense for the content. **To only avoid** those contents to wrap, it can be done via flex for instance https://plnkr.co/edit/G31uv5PMdRTgUjoal5Yg?p=preview if i understood the question .... (`.paragraphs` CSS updated + text has to be wrap into `<p>` and `<img/>` is reordered via CSS

Answer (score 0):

The *flex* property has been created for that purpose :

```css
.main {
  display : flex;
  justify-content : space-around;
  background-color : black;
}

.main .sub {
  width : 100px;
  height : 100px;
  background-color : red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub"><p>First div</p></div>
  <div class="sub"><p>Second div</p></div>
  <div class="sub"><p>Third div</p></div>
</div>
```

You can change the value of *justify-content* with *space-between*, that's up to your taste.